# chrome extension : OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have uploaded my extension to web-store and my extensions IDs are same on web-store dashboard and in local installation. I have also setup my credentials on google-api against chrome-app and put client_id in the manifest and set permission for "identity".

When I call `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` , it returns this error `OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request'` .. **no more clues**

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Did you wind up finding the answer for this?